# binary submission to the App Store - Invalid Code Signing Entitlements

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store

After submitting binary file to the app store I'm receving following message from apple:

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent binary submission for "App_name".  The following issues will need to be corrected in order for your application to proceed to review:

Invalid Code Signing Entitlements -  Your application bundle's signature contains ubiquity code signing entitlements that are not supported.

Specifically,    value "( MCCNWJ4W7F.* )" for key "com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers"  in  is not supported.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that for iCloud?  I wouldn't have thought they'd be accepting apps that support iCloud yet.

Comment: My publisher sent me provisioning profile and certificate. I built the application for distribution and the message was received after uploading binary by my publisher. Do I have to change anything in Xcode? Or maybe something is wrong in provisioning profile/certificate? Where is that iCloud setting? How to switch it off?

Comment: Go to the provisioning portal, switch off iCloud for that app ID, and regenerate the provisioning profile.

Comment: Jim, how can I switch off iCloud in the provisioning portal? what do I click? I've been looking for the checkbox for the last half an hour:(

Comment: Same problem here - Apple screwed up, and force-enabled iCloud everywhere. We've got one iTunes account that is able to download "normal" profiles, and another that's still stuck on broken iCloud ones. No response from Apple yet :(.